# JavaScript / SVG

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I want to get 4 buttons in javascript to change the colour of the square in svg when clicking on them

So far I have the following code

```
<html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="100%"height="100%"version="1.1"
<svg xmlns="http://www.adobe.com/svg">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

function chooseColor1() {

document.getElementsById("mySqaure")[0].style.color = "green";


        }

        function chooseColor2() {

            document.getElementsById("mySqaure")[0].style.color = "pink";

        }

        function chooseColor3() {

            document.getElementsById("mySqaure")[0].style.color = "purple";

        }

        function chooseColor4() {

            document.getElementsById("mySqaure")[0].style.color = "blue";

        }



    ]]>
 </script>
 `<g
    id="firstGroup">
    <rect id = "mySquare" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"  fill="grey" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

  </g>

    <form onsubmit="return false">
       <input type="button" value="green" onclick="chooseColor1()"/>
        <input type="button" value="pink" onclick="chooseColor2()"/>
         <input type="button" value="purple" onclick="chooseColor3()"/>
          <input type="button" value="blue" onclick="chooseColor4()"/>
    </form>
</svg>

</html>
```

Comment: And what problem are you having..?

Comment: @DavidThomas I can get the svg square to show up but i cant get the buttons in the form to show and work

Comment: I don't think `form` and `script` elements are allowed inside `svg`. Place them outside. also the rest of you markup is messed up (no body and head element, xml header and doctype inside html? That's all just wrong) Review the basic structure of HTML documents.

Comment: Also I'm not sure whether `type="text/ecmascript"` is valid... just omit it.

Comment: Pretty broken svg example, form elements and custom namespaces (`xmlns="http://www.adobe.com/svg"`). Wouldn't validate as svg.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your button functions aren't working is likely to be due to a misspelling.  In your functions you're referring to an element with id "mySqaure" but your element's id is actually "mySquare".

I'm not sure why the buttons aren't appearing as the tags look well-formed, but you do appear to have a "`" character just before the g tag (not sure if this crept in when you copied the code into this page).

Edit: Your first SVG tag isn't closed properly (doesn't have /> at the end).

Comment: Textbook case of mis-spelling!